# UIScrollView not scrolling all the way down

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

```
class ESA: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var textScroll: UIScrollView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textScroll.scrollEnabled = true
    textScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake (375, 1500)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

My View controller is set to 1500 and so is the Scroll View. However, I can only scroll a little bit down (just under halfway). Any ideas what would be causing this?

Comment: How is your view controller height set to 1500?

Comment: freeform...you can then change the dimensions

Comment: have you tried to set it in viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Comment: never heard of that. Either way, If I increase the height in the code it works. But I'm just wondering why when I match it to the height of the controller it doesn't work.

Comment: did you set constraints for your scroll view? is so, what are they?

Comment: the same as the View Controller

Comment: I had both view controller and scroll view height set to 1500 and was still able to scroll. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5296996/ScrollView.zip

Comment: Is there a tab bar or a nav bar that it is embedded in?

Comment: Ya and that's another issue I have, the scroll bar doesn't start at the top and ends within the tab bar

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure you don't have any constraints set to vertically fix the scrollview to the center. I had the same problem, but once I updated the constraints to simply be fixed 0 pixels from the top, it went from scrolling only half way down, to scrolling the entire way down.